# Intuitive explanation of Homotopy Equivalence vs Homeomorphism geometrically

Tags: algebraic-topology, geometric-topology

I am learning these two notions and I was convinced that homotopy equivalence is a weaker condition(thus more spaces can be homotopy equivalent to one another) than homeomorphism in describing relationship between two topological spaces. Thus, homotopy equivalence is used to determine whether two spaces are NOT homeomorphism by finding two spaces are NOT homotopy equivalent.

Intuitively, on the other hand, when determining whether two spaces are homeomorphism or not geometrically, I noticed that people check to see if they can "transform" one space to the other. For example, the author of the book I'm reading claims that hemisphere(boundary not included) in $S^n$ is homeomorphic to $B_1(0)$ by projection. Can we make a similar claim for homotopy equivalence? Or, is this approach accurate for determining whether two spaces are homeomorphic or not?

Comment: @JulianQuast: They're talking about a hemisphere included in $S^n$, though.

Comment: But if we pick one point $x$ in $S^n$ and choose an open hemisphere containing $x$,  it's essentially a disc so maybe it is contractible so homeomorphic to $B_1(0)$. Is it true?

Comment: Ok, this is a homeomorphism and in particular a homotopy equivalence.

Comment: Example: $\mathbb{R}^n \simeq *$ the one-point space, but they are clearly not homeomorphic.

Comment: Yes, but I mean intuitively speaking, people think of homeomorphism as the property of "being able to be deformed into one another without cutting" but the counterexample you give me suggests that there is some degree to it, I guess. I cannot deform too much to have homeomorphism, but maybe homotopy equivalence allows that.

Comment: Another good example to keep in mind is the circle with a line segment sticking out of it. This is homotopy equivalent to the circle (imagine contracting the line segment to the point $P$ at which it meets the circle), but not homeomophic to it since no open neighborhood of $P$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R$ (which can itself be proved by noting that the complement of a point in $\mathbb R$ always has $2$ connected components, while the complement of $P$ in any neighborhood (other than the whole space) has $3$ connected components).

Comment: Or more directly, just note that if you delete any point on the line segment you get two connected components, while the complement of a point on a circle is connected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To verify both homeomorphism and homotopy equivalence you have a similar process: you must verify the *existence* of a function that satisfies certain properties. One common way of doing this is to *construct* the appropriate function (i.e. to write down a formula for that function), and then to verify the appropriate properties. So yes, verifying homotopy equivalence is similar to verifying homeomorphism. However, as you can see when you examine the definitions, it is similar but more complicated.

So to prove $X$ and $Y$ are homeomorphic, you need to construct a bijective function $f : X \to Y$ and verify that $f$ is continuous and $f^{-1} : Y \to X$ is continuous.

But to prove $X$ and $Y$ are homotopy equivalent is more complicated. You need to construct continuous function $f : X \to Y$, and $g : Y \to X$, and $F : X \times [0,1] \to X$, and $G : Y \times [0,1] \to Y$, and you must verify that $F(x,0)=g \circ f(x)$, $F(x,1)=x$, $G(y,0) = f \circ g(y)$, and $F(y,1)=y$.

The functions $F$ and $G$ are "homotopies", and they make rigorous the intuition of "deforming".